Why did Hashem create the Ohr HaGanuz?
Rashi says on a Pasuk in Parshas Bereishes that Hashem created the Ohr HaGanuz / a very special light. Hashem then took away this light and reserved it for when Moshiach comes - so if Hashem knew that he wasn't going to need this light until later on, then why did he create it?

It is also stated that Hashem “wanted to create the world with the attributes of justice, but saw that the world would not last, and partnered with it the attribute of mercy.” I would assume the quoted midrash is speaking in the same sense, that although Hashem surely knew it would turn out that way, he wanted it to be part of the creation process.

Relevant https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/144636/31534

Exactly for that reason. It's needed for a certain time.

If He created on six days, rested on the seventh, and thousands of years later worked an eighth day we wouldn't have our convenient weekly cycle.
Seven is also an important numerology number and if God was known to make extra creations now and then, it would break the significance of the 7 days of creation and the other 7s we have.

I have 3 answers to this question:

There is a Pasuk in Koheles that reads:


מַה־שֶּֽׁהָיָה֙ ה֣וּא שֶׁיִּֽהְיֶ֔ה וּמַ֨ה־שֶּׁנַּֽעֲשָׂ֔ה ה֖וּא שֶׁיֵּֽעָשֶׂ֑ה וְאֵ֥ין כָּל־חָדָ֖שׁ תַּ֥חַת הַשָּֽׁמֶשׁ

"What has been is what will be, and what has been done is what will be done, and there is nothing new under the sun"*
This shows that there is nothing new ever created and that everything was create originally by the creation of the world.

So that people can find the Ohr HaGanuz through learning Torah.
The Zohar says that once a week on Shabbos this light is shown on us, and therefore Hashem created it by Brias HaOlam.


Your comment tells us that Ohr haGanuz exists or is shown, but why did Hashem create it? 1. Could you provide explicit sources for your statements 2 and 3 (unless these are your own chiddushim)?


Perhaps your answer 2 can be rephrased as "so that people could find Ohr haGanuz by learning the Torah".


Perhaps the answer 3 can also be modified "so that people who keep Shabbos could merit seeing this light".


